# What Dupont wires fit into pin machine headers?

Tags: wire-size, pin-headers

I currently only have [machine pin headers](https://shop13030.hstatic.dk/upload_dir/shop/00743-1_46.jpg) lying around.
[image]

However, none of my [Dupont wires](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Ur4maP7nBKNjSZLeq6zxCFXak/HoBiMart-10-40p-20cm-Male-to-Male-2-54mm-Dupont-Wire-Cable-Line-jumper-cable-wires.jpg_640x640.jpg) fit into them.

[image]

What sort of pre-made wire fit into these, and what are they named?

Comment: Did you mean "premade" instead of "remade"?

Comment: I would guess ones with machine pin ends.

Comment: Machine pin headers aren't what you want for prototyping wires.  Buy suitable socket headers instead, or use pin headers on the board and socket end wires.

Answer (score 4):

> What sort of wire fit into this [style of machined pin headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hu1A.jpg), and what are they named?

These types of machined headers aren't intended for wires.  They are intended for pins of ICs in SIP or DIP packages.

Comment: They also work beautifully for 3mm / 5mm LEDs :)